# can not copy an item in App Sandbox

Tags: iphone, ios

There are these directories I am working on it

> path1 is /var/mobile/Applications/891AE5A9-9462-463E-9DA9-BB469D867E0E/Documents/bground.png
> path2 is /var/mobile/Applications/891AE5A9-9462-463E-9DA9-BB469D867E0E/MyApp.app

Next, I am trying to copy  **bground.png** from path1 directory into path2 by doing

> BOOL done = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:path1 toPath:path2 error:&error];
>
> ```
> if ( done != YES ) {
>     NSLog(@"error is %@",[error localizedDescription]);
> }
> ```

Unfortunately, my process is not successful.

Does any one experience it before, please advice me on this issue. Any comments are welcomed here.
Thanks

Comment: The output of the error message would be interesting.

Comment: Here it is :error is The operation couldnot be completed. (Cocoa error 516.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cocoa error 516 means NSFileWriteFileExistsError (documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html)). Try changing your code so that path2 gets

```
/var/mobile/Applications/891AE5A9-9462-463E-9DA9-BB469D867E0E/MyApp.app/bground.png
```

Comment: I have just gave it a try and still not successful after all. My question is can we import data to bundle's sub directory, I think bundle's sub directory is encrypted, so we can read data on it but we are prohibited to write on it. I am still looking for some reference about this issue....

Comment: I just tried it in practice and had no problems creating files in my bundle's sub directory. Documentation for NSFileManager states that dstPath (your path2) must include the filename. There must be something else going wrong...

Comment: Have you tried to run the app on the device and then try to copy an item to bundle's sub directory ( such as App.app )

Comment: Worked on both, device and simulator. And yes, the directory was MyApp.app. I actually didn't copy an existing file, but downloaded a file and saved it in that directory.

Comment: Still not work...Dont know why...Can you paste a block of codes to download and save a file in MyApp.app at here so that I can do a comparison..( if you dont mind )

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I produced here. Seems like you were right with your assumption of not beeing able to write to that directory. I could do this because my iPhone is jailbreaked. After booting non-jailbreaked the same code doesn't create files in that directory any more...

Comment: That makes sense to me now. Thanks for our great talks. It does help a lotttttt